# CSS frontend not load

Tags: magento2

I repare the error of CSS in frontend and backend, but the problem is that I use a theme in home page and it's load perfectly:

[image]

but in Held category I use custom theme and not load CSS:

[image]

Why?

I see that when I use setup:upgrade, frontend and backend not load css

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done a grunt refresh?

Comment: Yes but not load